# URL Link in Android Calendar Description

Tags: calendar, html

I have being using the iPhone with synced calendar events with a URL to a webpage in the description. On the iPhone or web Google calendar the URL is active. On the Android Calendar it is not. Is there anyway to have an active URL in an Android Calendar Event Description?

Answer (score 1):

I just created a calendar event with a fully qualified URL as the description and it became a live link when I viewed the event.

What format are you using for the URL?

(For what it's worth, I have an original Droid with Android 2.2.1.)